# Activity with Navigation component cause A Memory Leak after Start New Root Activity or Calling Finish()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, memory-leaks, leakcanary

My app start with this Activity **_ A _** Which has FragmentContainer that get initialized as following

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/register_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
    private var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment? = null
    private var navController: NavController? = null
    private fun setNavGraph() {
        navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.register_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment            
        navController = navHostFragment?.navController
        val graph = navController?.navInflater?.inflate(R.navigation.registration_process_graph)
        navController?.setGraph(graph !!, intent.extras)
 
    }
```

now when i try to open new Activity as a **root** i got a Memory Leak

```
      val intent = Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRA_MODEL, getViewModel().getDashboardResponse())
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        releaseInstance()
        startActivity(intent)
```

```
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.transition.TransitionManager class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static TransitionManager.sPendingTransitions
│                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Retaining 294.4 kB in 5955 objects
│    ↓ ArrayList[0]
│               ~~~
├─ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 89.6 kB in 1750 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.null
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 0
│    mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity
│    com.demo.bm.auth.ui.AuthActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    ↓ View.mContext
├─ android.view.ContextThemeWrapper instance
│    Leaking: YES (FrameLayout↑ is leaking and ContextThemeWrapper wraps an
│    Activity with Activity.mDestroyed true)
│    Retaining 48 B in 2 objects
│    mBase instance of com.demo.bm.auth.ui.AuthActivity with mDestroyed =
│    true
│    ↓ ContextWrapper.mBase
╰→ com.demo.bm.auth.ui.AuthActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.demo.bm.
​     auth.ui.AuthActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and
​     Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 30.6 kB in 971 objects
​     key = 9dec9a77-29b1-46a6-a8ef-143f2811a4d1
​     watchDurationMillis = 5590
​     retainedDurationMillis = 575
​     mApplication instance of com.demo.bm.demoApp
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
```

Kindly note that i have tried to remove all subViews and cleared local variables of Activity _ **A** _ before moving to DashboardActivity as following

```
        navHostFragment = null
        navController = null
         val navView = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.register_nav_host_fragment)
        (navView.parent as ViewManager).removeView(navView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Leak Canary log looks werid.

```
├─ android.widget.FrameLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    Retaining 89.6 kB in 1750 objects
│    View is part of a window view hierarchy
│    View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
│    View.mID = R.id.null
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 0
│    mContext instance of android.view.ContextThemeWrapper, wrapping activity
```

FrameLayout is detached but it is also part of a window view hierarchy. How that could be possible?.
I'm not sure but did you add FrameLayout directly to the window or used `WindowManager` like this?

```
// using window API
window.addContentView(FrameLayout(this), null)
// using acitivity API
this@MainActivity.addContentView(FrameLayout(this), null)
// using WindowManager API
windowManager.addView(FrameLayout(this), ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Comment: Maybe because **FragmentContainerView** is child of **FrameLayout** 
and it is just placed with in the activity.xml  as i have posted and android OS is responsible for all inflation process

Comment: @AbdallaMaged
  So, where did that R.id.null FrameLayout came from? It looks like that framelayout is causing the leak. I need more detail about that R.id.null view.

Comment: Where can it be , as I have posted, the activity xml has nothing more than FragmentContainer and also I Have Removed all
subviews before moving to next activity